# Spark Streaming job doesn't fail when the connection to Kafka cannot be established

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using Spark Streaming on AWS EMR to connect to a Kafka cluster on AWS MSK. I'm using spark-sql-kafka-0-10 with Spark 2.4.3.

If the security groups are not correctly configured, the Spark Streaming jobs get stuck for hours with the following warning:

```
20/06/29 14:10:42 WARN NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source...] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

I would expect the job to fail if the connection cannot be established.

Is there a way I can make the job fail? All the timeout values are set to the default values.

Answer (score -1):

This warning message occurs because you don't have connectivity to one or more than one of the brokers of your Kafka cluster. (might also happen in case when new brokers are added to the existing cluster and you are not aware of it)

Before setting up a job, I would recommend checking for connectivity between the *producer's server* and all the *kafka brokers* using `telnet`

Comment: All the brokers are set up in the Kafka properties. Connectivity is an issue because Spark is not able to communicate with Kafka. The job is stuck for hours without sending/receiving data. It would be good to have a timeout setting to make the job failing if this situation happens.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, Have you found any workaround for this

Comment: @lorenzotenti - Updated my answer

Comment: The same issue. Is it a known issue?